# osdk flight controller sample doesn't work

Tags: dji-sdk

I'm trying to run osdk3.6 sample
'djiosdk-flightcontrol-sample'
with Matrice600 pro simulator.

when I select,

```
[a] Monitored Takeoff + Landing
```

It works well, but when I select

```
[b]Monitored Takeoff + Position Control + Landing
```

UAV successfully takes off but after that It doesn't move at all .
and After 3 times timeouts It lands with RTH beep.

It seems

```
vehicle->control->positionAndYawCtrl()
```

doesn't work in my environment.

Are there any settings I should confirm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by myself.

In Android DJI GO, there are settings of moveable range of drone and I had set these limits.
with removing these range limits, sample code has worked fine.

Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Please try these 3 independent troubleshooting steps:**

- Check that your RC is on F mode
- Check that your batteries have a    charge of over 15%
- Run the Obtain Control Authority API before    Monitored Takeoff